# Mysql threads stuck in 'query end', how to prevent furious flushing

Tags: mysql, buffer, innodb, flush

MySQL became unresponsive as many simple UPDATE and INSERT threads were stuck in 'query end' state.

```
---TRANSACTION F528F961, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 858 sec
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
 MySQL thread id 82683520, OS thread handle 0x7f73a6925700, query id 14714499253 192.168.1.22 wms query end
UPDATE  `users`
    SET `id` = '6016', `es_id` = '4817', `department_id` = '4',
        `schedule_id` = '1', `username` = 'john.doe',
        `user_role` = 'Guest,Admin,Picker',
        `status` = '1', `team` = '2', `email` = NULL,
        `wms_user` = '1', `logged_in_time` = '2016-02-01 07:06:45',
        `last_activity` = '2016-02-01 13:07:49',
        `session_id` = 'qbei0rrfiu05l9olcckh6sg976'
    WHERE  (id = 6016)
```

CPU load went up, Disk IO went up, hit ratio went down.
[CPU Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAxKL.jpg) /  [Disk IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5BdU.jpg)
Even "use db" and "show master status" threads showed up in the slow log.

From what I figure this is 'furious flushing'. 
A user ran a large SELECT statement through the applcation. The select inner joins 12 InnoDB tables that have `sum(data_length + index_length) = 11.2G`and sorts the results. The thing is that this is not an unusual query. It runs very often but with a much smaller working set:

`# Query_time: 1.737293  Lock_time: 0.000027 Rows_sent: 7051  Rows_examined: 1109050`

This time the user wanted data from the past 2 months, which lead to:

`# Query_time: 370.063806  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 919  Rows_examined: 27994638`

From Engine InnoDB Status:

`Main thread process no. 24701, id 140134828910336, state: flushing buffer pool pages
 0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 894332.73 reads/s`

Server runs Debian 6.0.4, MySQL 5.5.31 Community Edition, 32 core CPU at 2.60GHz / 64GB RAM /  SSD

My.cnf:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size =  40G 
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_thead_concurrency = 0 ## modified to 32 after crash
innodb_read_io_threads  = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 4 
innodb_old_blocks_pct = 37 
innodb_flush_method=NULL ## would change to O_DIRECT but needs restart
innodb_old_blocks_time = 0 ## modified to 1000 after crash
```

This was an probably an isolated case, but I want to know how I can prevent this in the future. Please offer your input. Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide few extra information, such as 1. "select ... for update" query is used by application or not? 2. whether indexing exists on 'id' column of the table `users`. 3. query fired just before the update statement.

Comment: Id is primary key for users and there are only simple selects. The update statements run every time a user issues an action as the application logs last user action every time. Within the time frame that the degradation occured, over a hundred of these kind statements were issued.

Comment: is it fired by a trigger? please explain "The update statements run every time a user issues an action as the application logs last user action every time". If an action changes 100 records, then does this update gets fired 100 times..?

Comment: For SSDs, turn off `innodb_flush_neighbors`, increase `innodb_io_capacity` and `innodb_io_capacity_max`

Comment: Consider other setting during the `SELECTs` for `tx_isolation`.

Comment: I've increased io_capacity, but unfortunately this server runs 5.5 so I can't configure the rest. An upgrade is in plan, though. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Build Summary tables for the users.  This will

- Keep the `SELECTs` from slowing down the `UPDATEs`.
- Make the `SELECTs` run 10x faster.
- Decrease overall system usage.

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).